# Datastudio: REGEXP_Extract the last part of URL

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I am looking to extract the last part of the URL, which looks like this:

> https://www.website.com/cat1/cat2/naming/id.html

I've been trying to edit this:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Product URL,'/([\\w-]+)$')
```

and I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get just `id` as the output.

The output of the above gets me a null value. If I remove the `$`, I get `www`.

What is the best way to get the `id`, between the last slash and before the `.html`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Product URL,'/([^/]*)\\.[^/.]*$')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hT3PW9/1).

*Details*

- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `[^/.]*` - zero or more chars other than `/ and` .`
- `$` - end of string.

Another possible solution is matching up to the first `.` char:

```
/([^./]*)[^/]*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hT3PW9/2). Here, `([^./]*)` captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `.` and `/` chars, and then `[^/]*$` matches any zero or more chars other than `/` till the end of string.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I added an additional \ and it worked:

/([^/]*)\\.[^/.]*$

Comment: @quibi Right, you need to double escape the backslash since a ``\`` char is used to form string escape sequences, like `\t`, `\r`, `\n`, etc.